# SQLServer replication between windows and linux server

Tags: sql-server, docker, replication

I'm trying to setup a replication between a SQLServer 2016 in a windows server and a SQLServer 2019 host in linux server.

The linux instance run in a kubernetes setup and the docker image is simcube/mssqlserver-2019.

I set my publication as a transactional pull publication and the distribution default snapshot folder is D:\Data\ReplicationData.

When I check the synchronization status, I have this error:

The process could not read file 'D:\Data\ReplicationData\unc\SUST5050_CORPORATIF PROD_WEBSITE\20230207080810\UtilisationExplosee2_100.pre' due to OS error 5.

Do you have any clues on what could be the problem?

I verified that the Agent process account and the subscriber connection credentials were correct.

I openned port 137, 138, 139, 445, 1433 on the linux server.

Answer (score 0):

> The process could not read file 'D:\Data\ReplicationData\unc\SUST5050_CORPORATIF PROD_WEBSITE\20230207080810\UtilisationExplosee2_100.pre' due to OS error 5.

This is indicative of a permissions issue on that folder share. Please make sure your `D:\Data\ReplicationData` folder (and all subfolders / files) are provisioned with Read / Write access to the account used in your replication topology.